# нужно выровнять строки в списках списков

Tags: python, строки, list

Читаю книжку "Автоматизация рутинных задач",
вроде нормально выучил главу о строках, но задачу для проверки решить не могу.
Вот ссылки на задачу:
https://wampi.ru/image/69wpG5f
https://wampi.ru/image/69wp7vy

Вот как я пытался сделать:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bop', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(tableData):
    for element1 in tableData[0]:
        len_element1 = len(element1)
    for element2 in tableData[1]:
        element2.rjust(len_element1)
    for element3 in tableData[2]:
        element3.rjust(len_element1)
        print(element1 + ' ' +  element2 + ' ' + element3)


printTable(tableData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея такая была?

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bop', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(data):
    show = ""
    for i in data:
        show += "\n"
        for j in i:
            show += j + ' '
    return show

print(printTable(tableData))
```

Comment: Похоже, но я бы до такого не додумался)) Спасибо большое.